# How to override an attribute in a class' __init__ method?

Tags: python

If there's a class like:

```
class MyFunObject(object)
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "http://myurl.com"
```

When I instantiate that class, can I not override the `url` attribute somehow?

If I do:

```
server = MyFunObject(url="http://www.google.com")
```

I get:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'url'
```

Is there way to override an attribute that's defined in the class' `__init__()` method?

Comment: Change the signature of `__init__` to `__init__(self, url)` and set `self.url = url or 'http://myurl.com'`

Comment: For classes with simple initialization, you should probably use [the attrs library](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/)

Comment: You need to get your terminology straight. In Python, "property" != "attribute", and one instantiates a _class_.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
class MyFunObject(object):

    def __init__(self, url="http://myurl.com"):
        self.url = url

    def Printurl(self)
        print(self.url)

obj = MyFunObject("http://www.google.com")
obj.Printurl()
```

Output:

```
http://www.google.com
```

If suppose:

```
 obj1 = MyFunObject()
 obj1.Printurl()
```

Output:

```
 http://myurl.com
```

Explanation:

As your function call is having a keyword argument `url` it is expecting the parameter in the `__init__`. If you add default value in `__init__` if the user didn't pass the argument in object declaration then it will take the default one.

Comment: To preserve the option to not pass an argument and use the default URL, you'd make the initializer definition `def __init__(self, url="http://myurl.com"):`

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Thanks. It is also a point to mention. Updated now

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to / can't change the code of the class, remember that a Python object's attributes are all public. So unless you're concerned with changing `url` before `__init__()` does any further processing, you can do the following:

```
>>> server = MyFunObject()
>>> server.url = 'http://www.google.com'
>>> print(server.url)
'http://www.google.com'
```